# Cpanel email using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, cpanel, nodemailer

I was using my google account to send emails in my application in development but now in production my client gave me cpanel email. I am using nodemailer module of nodejs to sending an emails. So i dont have enough knowledge of cpanel. i am able to login  with my email credentials at mydomain.name/webmail.

I found code snippet to use cpanel email in nodemail like

```
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'hostname',
    port: 25,
    auth: {
        user: '----domain.com',
        pass: '********'
    }

    var mailOptions = {
        from: '-----@domain.com', 
        to: '-------@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'Order Recipt',
        text: 'html' 
    };
```

So i didn't get what is port and host, where we have to configure it.

So help me how to use cpanel email in my application, what are the steps i have to follow.

Currently i am using nodemailer with my google account email like

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: configurationHolder.config.emailFrom,
        pass: configurationHolder.config.emailPassword
    }
});

var sendEmail = function (fromEmail, toEmail, subject, emailBody, html) {

        transporter.sendMail({
            from: fromEmail,
            to: toEmail,
            subject: subject,
            text: emailBody,
            html: html
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem. The host name doesn't seem to work for me from the link and video!

Answer (score 3):

follow these steps : it worked for the mail id which I had created using cpanel

[image]

2 things to note here
a) in host where you had given the host name as "abc.com".. instead you can give the URL of the webmail too.. [remove the https].. as seen below in the image [do not include **:2096** `as seen in the image or any number/port info which you see in the url`
[image]
b) if you still see an error, use "abc.com" and ensure you are using 465 and set the

> secure : true

else if you are using other than 465; then set

> secure : false

Answer (score 2):

You can get this detail from the cpanel itself.  [see this link](https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/cPanel-Locating-Email-Server-Settings) or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mB9AVFLdZ6U)

you only need hostname and port number detail, actually.

For  username and password. You have to create one email Account in cpanel.

Comment: Thanks,i see the links and got information. Can we have to setup smtp server, because host is not working.i am getting this error { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND]
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  command: 'CONN' }

Comment: did you tried , sending mail normally from some webmail interface.  I think beyond this point you need to ask help from your service provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 host: "mail.*********.com",//this is the trick works for me, you have to insert 'mail' keyword before your domain name
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
user: "donotreply@***********.com",
      pass: "************",
    },
  });
```